# How to do one fetch (async/promise) and use that data in many methods?

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, promise

I have one fetch request which gives me data.
I need to use that data in different methods, but I do not want to have the same request many times in the Network.
How can I fetch data, for example, have one method for that and use it in different methods at the same service.

```
export class MediaService {
  constructor(private mediaAppApiService: MediaAppApiService) {}

  private getMedia() {
    const result = this.mediaAppApiService
      .getDigitalMedia()
      .then((item) => {
        const { media } = item;

        return media;
      });

    return Promise.resolve(media);
  }

  public getMediaHours() {
    const mediaHours = this.getMedia().then((media) => {
      return media.map((value) => {
        const { id, isDefault } = value;
        return {
          id,
          status: isDefault ? StatusCodes.ACTIVE : StatusCodes.INACTIVE,
        };
      });
    });

    return Promise.resolve(mediaHours);
  }

  public getRecency() {
    const recency = this.getMedia().then((media) => {
      return media.find((value) => value.isDefault).name;
    });

    return Promise.resolve(recency);
  }
}
```

Comment: Keep a variable to store data and call getMedia on load/click and set the result into variable. Then instead of calling this.getMedia(), use that variable.

Comment: Or try to use observable instead of promise with rxjs share() operator.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally try and use RXJS Store and persist this data into the application's state as soon as it's retrieved. In this way all your application components which are interested can subscribe to this data and it will be available centrally for all.